# Programs too slow and prisoners not attending to them in Prison Architect

Tags: prison-architect

My prisoners' needs are low
[image]

And this is my daily regime
[image]

But my programs are really slow and only 2-3 people attending to classes. I'm waiting for days but still just 8 prisoners passed.
[image]

Can you tell me what's wrong with my prison ? Should i increase number of prisoners to increase education?

Comment: By that screenshot, you only have 34 prisoners, and per the sheet a majority have attempted the class already.  You just need to bring more in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The two ways I know of to increase program interest:

1. Increase the number of prisoners - The more prisoners, the more chances one is to be interested in a program.
2. Reduce suppression - Suppressed prisoners are not interested in learning. Remove armed guards and severe punishments for minor infractions to reduce suppression.

Comment: any tips for reducing suppression? decreasing guards number?

Comment: Remove armed guards and severe punishments for minor infractions to reduce suppression

Comment: I've removed armed guards and now everything went out of my control :D lot's riots.

Comment: @Eray Now all you need is the Ultra Violence Mod!

Comment: No Finn! :D I will be a good manager :D

Answer (score 1):

The prisoners will only attend classes and want to further themselves if they are not suppressed.

From the Dev Wiki:

> Most programs are voluntary, but prisoners will be less likely to volunteer for programs if they are badly treated

Some things that help with this is not having armed guards around as that will automatically suppress any prisoner around. However, you can have as many regular guards as you want as that does not affect suppression.

Another thing you can do is make them have the status of "Well Fed" which is where you serve high quality, high quantity food.

From Alpha 12:

> Suppressed: Prisoners locked in Solitary Confinement will become suppressed and compliant due to their harsh treatment. These suppressed prisoners are much less likely to cause trouble.
>
> Well Fed: Prisoners who eat well will become "well fed", contributing to the good feeling in the prison.
> Well fed prisoners are much less likely to cause trouble.